# array.length is zero after push

Tags: angular, rxjs

Hello I try to push dataUrl into array but after for loop array.length is still zero, here is code example

```
public imageUrl: any[] = [];

upload($event) {
 let files = $event.target.files;
 for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
  reader.onload = () => {
   this.imageUrl.push(reader.result);
  } 
 }
 console.log(this.imageUrl.length) // here is a problem
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution after researching

```
public chooseImages($event: any) {
       this.selectedFiles = $event.target.files;
       let onload = null;

       for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; i++) {
         let reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFiles[i]);

         onload = new Promise((res, rej) => {
           reader.onloadend = () => {
             this._prevImg.push(reader.result);
             this._subject.next(this._prevImg);
             res(this._prevImg);
             rej(`onload error`);
           }
         });
       }

       onload.then((arr: any[]) => {
         this._upload(arr.length);
       }).catch((err: any) => {
         console.log(`error happened ${err}`);
       });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This (`onload`):

```
  reader.onload = () => {
   this.imageUrl.push(reader.result);
  }
```

is asynchronous operation.So console.log next to it, wont work because `onload` is added to event loop and not yet executed.

To test, can wrap with `setTimeout`:

`setTimeout(() => console.log(this.imageUrl.length), 1000)`;

Maybe easiest way is with Promise.all (note, I havent tested this, but concept must be ledgit:

```
async upload(event) {
 return Promise.all(
   ...event.target.files.map(file => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      })
    })
  } 
}

mageUrl = await upload($event);
```

Comment: if I convert `imageUrl` to `Observable<any[]>` can I subscribe it after push ?

Comment: Updated possible solution. However would be nice if there was some native way from  `FileReader` API

Comment: ah... thank you I'll check your code, if it will work I close a question